# How efficient is moving a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, move

I'm trying to gain a better grip as to when should I implement move semantics on my code or just delegate that to the compiler, and while performing some basic profiling/benchmarking I got confused as to why moving a vector is actually taking longer than copying it:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

#define REPS 10000000

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    // ----------------------------------------------------

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock clock;

    auto start = clock.now();
    for (int i = 0; i < REPS; i++) {
        std::vector< float >(700, 1.54343);
    }
    auto end = clock.now();

    std::cout << "Instantiating vector [x" << std::to_string(REPS) << "]: " << std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(end - start).count() << " ms" << std::endl;

    // ----------------------------------------------------

    std::vector< float > src(700, 1.54343);

    start = clock.now();
    for (int i = 0; i < REPS; i++) {
        std::vector< float > dst = src;
    }
    end = clock.now();

    std::cout << "Copying from rvalue [x" << std::to_string(REPS) << "]: " << std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(end - start).count() << " ms" << std::endl;

    // ----------------------------------------------------


    start = clock.now();
    for (int i = 0; i < REPS; i++) {
        std::vector< float > dst = std::vector< float >(700, 1.54343);  // vector< float >(700, 1.54343);
    }
    end = clock.now();

    std::cout << "Moving from a temporary [x" << std::to_string(REPS) << "]: " << std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(end - start).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

I get the follwing output:

```
Instantiating vector [x10000000]: 1160 ms
Copying from rvalue [x10000000]: 1167 ms
Moving from a temporary [x10000000]: 1491 ms
```

But shouldn't moving it, *at worst*, be as efficient as copying it (or in this case, initializing a new one)? Is there anything wrong with how I'm profiling this code?

Weirdly enough, I also noticed that commenting the first loop had a significant impact on the time:

```
Instantiating vector [x10000000]: 0 ms
Copying from rvalue [x10000000]: 1176 ms
Moving from a temporary [x10000000]: 1049 ms
```

Which may have an obvious explanation, but seems quite strange to me.

Comment: The benchmarks are meaningless for at least two different reasons. One, the compiler can deduce that completely optimizing away both loops has no observable effects, and it is likely that some, or most of both loops simply does not get compiled. Two, unless the results are repeatable, this kind of a difference is line noise.

Comment: All of these tests have no observable behavior. The compiler can optimize them in unexpected ways. This is not a really meaningful test. Specially since `std::vector< float > dst = std::vector< float >(700, 1.54343);` performs no move. It is an initialization it's just a longer way of writing `std::vector< float > dst (700, 1.54343);`. It doesn't create a temporary that is moved from. Finally, make sure you are compiling with optimizations enabled. Measuring unoptimized builds is not meaningful.

Comment: There's also a reasonable chance that despite all this, you'll end up measuring other things, such as the performance of the allocator itself, differences between single-value construction and straight memory copies, heap fragmentation, and memory cache.

Comment: You're not really testing between moving and copying because your move test creates a completely new vector every iteration in addition to performing the move. Also are you compiling with optimization?

Comment: You move measurement also creates/initialize the temporary, as this, you compare (move+create) agains create or copy. Thats totally the wrong interpretation. The move operation is only "moving" an int and a pointer and invalidate a the original vector which should be less than measurable. And the compiler sees what you are doing which is without side effects nothing. So you can't get any real result in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

You're not moving correctly! In your snippets the line when you want to move, consists of one **creation operation** and one **assigning operation**, that take much longer than a single assignment.

If you want to calculate move operation, you can write something like this:

```
std::vector< float > dst = std::move(src);
```

My test result without this modification:

```
Instantiating vector [x10000000]: 22000 ms
Copying from rvalue [x10000000]: 19912 ms
Moving from a temporary [x10000000]: 22694 ms
```

My test result with this modification:

```
Instantiating vector [x10000000]: 23187 ms
Copying from rvalue [x10000000]: 20267 ms
Moving from a temporary [x10000000]: 593 ms
```

Comment: This benchmark isn't fair either, it'll move from `src` once then subsequent iterations `src` will be empty so if there were any performance difference for larger moves (there shouldn't be) this wouldn't show it